# Django sitemap for multilanguage website posts filter

Tags: python, django

I try to seperate my post on lang. in sitemap. but But for example, if there are 3 languages (en,fr,de), each post three added in sitemap.

example
my_sample_post_english in db language option "en"
my_sample_post_french in db language option "fr"

my sitemap create like this;

```
<url>
<loc>http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/post/vote/my_sample_post_english</loc>
<lastmod>2020-05-19</lastmod>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://127.0.0.1:8000/fr/post/vote/my_sample_post_english</loc>
<lastmod>2020-05-19</lastmod>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://127.0.0.1:8000/de/post/vote/my_sample_post_english</loc>
<lastmod>2020-05-19</lastmod>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
```

how can i filter post for languages? i want like this;

```
<url>
<loc>http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/post/vote/my_sample_post_english</loc>
<lastmod>2020-05-19</lastmod>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://127.0.0.1:8000/fr/post/vote/my_sample_post_french</loc>
<lastmod>2020-05-19</lastmod>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://127.0.0.1:8000/de/post/vote/my_sample_post_deutsch</loc>
<lastmod>2020-05-19</lastmod>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    ...
    path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
     name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

sitemaps.py

```
class BlogSitemap(Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5
    # this generates urls per language
    i18n = True

    def items(self):
        posts= Post.objects.filter(private=False)
        for b in posts:
            if b.language == 'en':
                b.language = str('en/') + b.language
            if b.language == 'fr':
                b.language = str('fr/') + b.language
            if b.language == 'de':
                b.language = str('de/') + b.language
        return posts

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.created_date
```

model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=350,verbose_name="PostTitle")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=353, null=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=settings.LANGUAGES, default="en")
    private = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False, verbose_name="Private Post")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post:addVote', args=[str(self.slug)])
```

Comment: By filtering false you get all the objects with value false. In your model why do you have a charfield for language while its should be a choice field

Comment: @ngawang13 can you help me please? how can i edit my model on your say? thanks...

Comment: Its hard to edit cause of the limited code..how are you handling the login in your view and how are rendering the post in your html

Comment: @ngawang13 thank you for intresting! im searcing solution.